# Ensure only intended objects passed from a function down to the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I have a complex function (not one liner) that receives an object, does some staff, and then it should return the same object back to the pipeline.

The function body opens files for writing, downloads something from the web service, etc. It also provides feedback to users by printing to console.

```
function($obj)
{
     do some staff
     more staff
     $obj
}
```

How do I ensure that only intended objects are returned back to the pipe line and nothing else like the text printed to the console or something that could be printed from the commands I run in the function body?

I think Write-Host should not impact the pipeline. But not sure about other commands. Perhaps, there is some way to do it. Did not find anything yet.

Comment: just use the return $obj statement at the end of your function so that is what will be returned.

Comment: @SagePourpre That doesn't make `$obj` necessarily the only object to be passed on to the pipeline.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching What ?! Well, I had to test this for myself and... Well, you are 100% right, of course. Another thing learned today ! Thanks !

Comment: I think return will not help, it just exits the function execution

Answer (score 2):

One strategy could be to wrap the function body in a separate block, dot-source it but suppress all output from it and then `return` whatever variable you need returned from outside the main block:

```
function Do-Stuff
{
  param($obj)

  $null = . {
    Get-Random
    $obj.Stuff = "Modified"
    Write-Output "All sorts of noise"
  }
  return $obj
}
```

Now you can do:

```
PS C:\> Do-Stuff -obj ([pscustomobject]@{Name="MyObject";Stuff="Original"})

Name     Stuff
----     -----
MyObject Modified
```

and only `$obj` is returned, everything else is swallowed by `$null`

Comment: This may work. Need to test what happens if any command generates some output, will it be lost or still shows in the console. I guess that depends if it is using write-verbose, write-host, etc

Comment: It will all be lost. You could pipe the `. {}` statement to `Write-Host` instead if you want it shown in the console

Answer (score 0):

Only the output stream will be passed to the pipeline. If you handle your console output with cmdlets like `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Warning` or (if you must) `Write-Host`, they will not interfere with the pipeline.

If you are using cmdlets with return values, that you do not wish to pass to the output stream or to a variable, you can pipe them to `Out-Null` as an option.

Comment: Is there a problem with Write-Host?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what each command can return. It could for example be silent and then print a message if encounters some error. Then it will go the the pipeline.

Comment: The classical answer to this is, that for most use cases there are better alternatives to `Write-Host`: fhttp://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: To repeat my answer: Only the output stream goes to the pipeline. If you suspect a command to write to your output stream, pipe its output to $null. Errors of native powershell cmdlets will go to the error stream and also not interfere with the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! Good article.